# react-native run-android Errors

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I've tried several times to run a simple app from React Native on my phone but I think there is a big wall in front of me. 
I previously have done following fixes:

1. change **default classpath** 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
2. **add google()** to repositories
3. change myapp/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties as following:

   ...distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-
   all.zip

   so my build.gradle is this:

```
    
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
            google()
        }
    }

    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    }
```

and now the issue is following error:
[image: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.]

I couldn't find more! I appreciate any help.

Comment: Finally, I find the solution by using Android Studio I will write it here as soon as possible.